# Basic algebra: associativity vs. commutativity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, associativity

While I was reviewing someone's homework for them, I came across the following:

$$(2)(x/3)(5) = 11$$

The workbook claims that rearranging the equation to:

$$(2)(5)(x/3) = 11$$

is an example of the associative property.

To me this looks much more like the commutative property. So, which is it?

Comment: It's commutativity.

Comment: @Mathematician42: I thought as much.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you squint (2)(x/3)5=(2)(5x/3) is a property of Associativity if we take "5x" to be simply how we write variables and coefficients.  The (2)(5x/3)=(2)(5)(x/3) is also associativity.  But that takes a bit of squinting and isn't an illustrative example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have to use both the associative and the commutative property.
$$2 \cdot\frac{x}{3} \cdot 5  \tag{1}$$
is an abbreviation for 
$$(2 \cdot\frac{x}{3}) \cdot 5\tag{2}$$
because multiplication is evaluated from left to right.
Now using associativity you can transform $(2)$ to

$$2 \cdot (\frac{x}{3} \cdot 5) \tag{3}$$
and now you use the commutative property to get

$$2 \cdot (5 \cdot \frac{x}{3} )\tag{4} $$

Now you use again associativity and get

$$(2 \cdot 5 ) \cdot \frac{x}{3} \tag{5} $$
which can be abbreviated to
$$2 \cdot 5  \cdot \frac{x}{3} \tag{6} $$

---

So if an operation $\cdot$ has the associative and the commutative property you have
$$(a \cdot b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) \cdot b, \forall\;  a,b,c \tag{7}$$
But   commutative property  is not sufficient that $(7)$ holds for the  operation $\cdot$. The following operation $\cdot$ will show  this :

```
. 0 1 2
-+-----
0|0 1 1
1|1 0 2
2|1 2 2
```

This operation is defined on the set $\{0,1,2\}$ and it is commutative because the Cayley table is symmetric. But you have
$$(0 \cdot  1) \cdot 2= 1 \cdot 2=2 \tag{8}$$

but
$$(0 \cdot 2) \cdot 1= 1 \cdot 1= 0  \tag{8}$$

So
$$(a \cdot b) \cdot c \ne (a \cdot c) \cdot b \tag{10}$$
for some $a,b,c$ even if $\cdot$ is commutative.

Comment: I question if it is convention to associate multiplication to the left any more than it is convention to associate it to the right.

Comment: I second Mees de Vries' comment.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Maybe there is no such convention for all [binary operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) but I think there is such a convention in "basic" algebra. At least I learned this long time ago in school, '-' and '/' are used in this way and computer languages like C use this convention (for floating point arithmetic)

Comment: Ah!  And now I understand fleablood's comment about squinting.  Thank you!